# Why a point and compact set being separated doesn't imply point being separated from every point of that compact set?

Tags: general-topology

Recently I've started studying dimension (inductive) theory and there's a logic behind the statement below I don't understand, so I need help. If there already exists a duplicate to my question, I apologize in advance, but I haven't found any. I'm only hoping answer isn't trivial.

Let $\left(X,\mathcal{T}\right)$ be separable, metrizable topological space.

**Statement**   Let $p \in X$ and $C$ nonempty, compact subset of $X$ not containing $p$. If $p$ and $c$ are separated in $X$ for every $c \in C$, then $p$ and $C$ are also separated in $X$.

**Problem** I don't understand why converse isn't true and why is $C$ being compact important.

*Definition I'm using is:*

Disjoint sets $A,B \subset X$ are said to be separated in $X$ if there exists a clopen set $U \subset X$ such that $A \subset U$ and $B \subset X/U $.

Comment: Where did you learn that the converse does not hold?

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen Author of the book I'm using (Nadler -  Dimension Theory: An Indroduction with Exercises) does not include converse implication in that statement, which is actually stated as lemma. What I'm thinking is that he could have left out converse implication because it _is_ trivial (and that was my first thought after reading it), but still it doesn't seem right to do so, since it doesn't mention (after or before) anything about converse implication. I doubted because statement is not written in its complete form.

Comment: Ah. Well, you shouldn't read too much into an omission like that. The converse is indeed trivial. Especially when it is stated as a lemma: Lemmas tend to be tightly focused on the intended usage, so adding the converse would just add noise if it is not required.

Comment: Oh, I see your point. Thank you very much for your advice and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Importance of compactness: Let $p=0$, $C=\{1,1/2,1/3,\ldots\}$, $X=\{p\}\cup C$.